# Derivation of B-Spline basis function recursion formula

Tags: bezier-curve, spline

Can anyone explain the logic behind the derivation of the seemingly magical b-spline basis function recursion formula (deBoor-Cox)

$N_{i,0}(u)=1    $  if $u_i\leq u <  u_{i+1}$
otherwise,  $=0$

$N_{i,p}(u)=\frac{u-u_{i}}{u_{i+p}-u_{i}}N_{i,p-1}(u)+
 \frac{u_{i+p+1}-u}{u_{i+p+1}-u_{i+1}}N_{i+1,p-1}(u)$

where $u_i$ is the ith knot in the knot vector, and  p is the degree of the polynomial basis function. So, $N_{i,p}(u)$ is the ith B-Spline basis function of degree p.

I know these are just piece-wise polynomials, but how was this formula derived? I tried deriving b-spline basis functions with a given knot vector by blending 2 bezier basis functions on 2 intervals together with continuity constraints at the knot, but it didn't work out..

Can anyone offer some intution behind this recursion formula?

Comment: See if the answer to this question helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682929/basic-b-spline-basis-function-question